# Selenium Click On

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape World Bank Natural Gas Price Forecast from here: https://knoema.com/ncszerf/natural-gas-prices-forecast-long-term-2017-to-2030-data-and-charts

Below is my code:

```
url = "https://knoema.com/ncszerf/natural-gas-prices-forecast-long-term-2017-to-2030-data-and-charts"
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

    #Open in  incognito mode
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--incognito")


    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\srai\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver", chrome_options = option)
    browser.get(url)

    #Create a timeout error option
    timeout = 20
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frozen-column-header"]/thead/tr/th[1]')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        browser.quit()

#Click on maximize above the table before running this code
#MASSIVE PROBLEM FOR AUTOMATION

#Could also use "id". 
# Xpath does not work well 
ng_element = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('pivot-table')
ng_num = [x.text for x in ng_element]
ng_num[-2:]

#Split to get individual elements from two elements
ng = ng_num[-2:]
split_list =[i.split() for i in ng]
split_list
```

As you can note from one of the comments, I am trying to automate this to fit into a larger script. The problem is that the code currently scrapes only 8 years of data from the table instead of all the thirteen years.

If I split the code in two chunks and go to the opened web page after running the first chunk to maximize the table to show all the years, and then find the elements by id/class_name, I get all 13 years.

So I am thinking I can use selenium to click on the maximize button, but I can't find id or class of the maximize button. This is just one idea I had, but please let me know if there are other options to scrape all 13 years of data.

Thank you!

Shashank

Answer (score 0):

Selenium way I think is good, but the way you are trying to create xpath is wrong. Because when you describe xpath like this `//*[@id="frozen-column-header"]/thead/tr/th[1]` you expect to be it the same way always, but it might change, add or anything else might change it. For example when I use this xpath in Google chrome f12 I can find 6 elements in DOM with exact xpath, so 1 issue why you'r script will never work, is because it doesn't know which element he must select / click.

So I would suggest to use xpath like this:

`(//*[@value='World Bank Commodity Price Data (Pink Sheet), Monthly Update']/ancestor::div[@class='bottom section']//div[@class='gadget-maximize'])[1]`

because this way you percisely are looking for exact table or etc.

**Explanation**

This xpath is looking for first identification of table (this identification is hard on this page, because first table doesn't has value within table, and 2nd has it, so I have found two tables where `value='World Bank Commodity Price Data (Pink Sheet), Monthly Update'` and then as I see that 1st element in page is what I need I can do this `(//*[@value='World Bank Commodity Price Data (Pink Sheet), Monthly Update'])[1]` to find the 1st element which I need. Try in Google Chrome f12 `Elements` tab), then this xpath `/ancestor::div[@class='bottom section']//div[@class='gadget-maximize']` is looking for ancestor that has this `class="gadget-maximize"` (that is the expand button) as it's child element (and also I see that I need 1st element by looking in html DOM), and I'm looking for 1st element in DOM with `[1]`. This will always work until there wount appear any other table with exact same value within table. (I say with exact, because now there is two in page).

**Tip**

Selecting css selector vs xpath selector. Css selector is faster, but can't have complex querys, xpath selector is much slower and maintaining xpath query is hard, but it can have complex querys with `or`, `and`, `not`, `contains` and etc statements with which you can build whatever you need xpath, if correctly created xpath, the maintainence is way lower then for other querys.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip. I think it is useful for future reference. I used the following xpath to call out the table:
 '//*[@id="091c1171-45ab-ae66-fe96-f76d73dd888f"]/div[2]/div[1]/div'

However, I still need to click on the maximize button, which was my initial problem. When I try the xpath for the maximize button ('//*[@id="091c1171-45ab-ae66-fe96-f76d73dd888f"]/div[1]/div/div[1') the server request is timed out, because the button can only be seen when you scroll on the web page. So I still need to find a way to click on the maximize button so that I can scrape the complete table.

Comment: Never depend on ID when bulding xpath, I see that the id you'r showing, could by dynamic, so it means everytime you request page url it might change, this is why you could get timeout. If you are trying to click on button that is in my xpath example, then you dont need to skroll down page, it's in the dom already when you request. Have you tryed just to request full html and look for what you need (atleast not full) I gues you will get that item, and then you just need to click the button. Now you'r xpath is finding table, but not the button, so that's why you get timeout. bad xpath :)

Comment: Thanks, Rolandas. I'll give that a try but what you're saying seems to make sense.